# How can I get width of columns (if defined) of ActiveRecord Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to adapt size of textboxes in HTML form to width of columns in database (defined by a :limit parameter in schema.rb).
I have found a "columns_hash" method, where this parameter is placed as "@limit", byt how I can get it out in the view? This is a ConnectionAdapter type which I canot parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YourARClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  limit = YourARClass.columns_hash["your_column_name"].try(:limit)
  if limit.present?
      validates_length_of :your_column_name, maximum: limit
  end
end
```